# Kotlin compiler not warning about potential null pointer exception

Tags: kotlin

I have this simple kotlin snipped that tries to map list elements to strings like this:

```kotlin
sealed class MySealedClass

class MyClass1 : MySealedClass()

class MyClass2 : MySealedClass()

fun doTheMapThing(elements: List<MySealedClass>): List<String> {
    return elements.flatMap {
        when (it) {
            is MyClass1 -> listOf("Yeah")
            is MyClass2 -> null
        }
    }
}
```

In the `flatMap`, the `when` either maps to a list or to `null`, so the effective return type of the `when` is `List<String>?`. I was a bit surprised to see this compiling without any issues. Shouldn't the kotlin compiler warn about this? When I extract the `when` to a function, I get a proper compiler error. Am I missing something here or could this be a bug?

Using kotlin 1.5.31

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Seems like a bug to me. Even if still using `when`, by assigning its result to a variable, it fails to compile - as expected

Comment: Thanks, I created a bug ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49658

Comment: I can reproduce this without involving a sealed class. `flatMap` anything, use `when { Random.nextBoolean() -> listOf(""); else -> null }` Lists of Number subtypes will trigger the proper compiler error. Lists of anything else I've tried (String, Char, Any) do not trigger the error. Any number of branches of the `when` can return null as long as one of them returns a List. The equivalent `if/else` expression triggers the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness: It was a bug. The fix will be released with Kotlin `1.7.0`. More details on that can be found here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49658

If you're interested in even more details, you can find the actual fix here: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/37d163d417bfe8ecd2e4baea3e5651906c96e150

A nice thing is that our example actually made it into the test code for kotlin:

```kotlin
fun doTheMapThing1(elements: List<CharSequence>): List<String> {
    return elements.flatMap {
        <!TYPE_MISMATCH_WARNING!>when (it) { // NullPointerException
            is String -> listOf("Yeah")
            else -> null
        }<!>
    }
}
```